# Are memory addresses in assembly language statically allocated at once?

Tags: c, assembly, memory-management, static, allocation

I would like to write a C-program that allocates 20,000 memory lines with each line containing 8 bytes and are labeled in the range 2500 to 24999.. The program actually simulates a simple assembly language IDE. All the 20,000 memory lines may or may not be used at once. Suggest me how to allocate memory for those locations in the C program. Should it be a static allocation?
Visit http://screencast.com/t/69T7u0avH

Comment: 1) What is a "memory line"? Do you mean you want to allocate 20000 * 8 bytes?

Comment: 2) What do you mean by "are labeled in the range 2500 and 24999" ?

Comment: 3) What do you mean by  "how to allocate memory for those locations"?

Comment: I don't want to discourage you, but the way that you have worded your question makes me wonder if this might be a little bit beyond you...

Comment: @Mark Segal, please check http://screencast.com/t/69T7u0avH

Comment: So you basically wish to allocate 20000 * 8 bytes, and access then as "8 byte lines". It is exactly the same as writing `long long array[20000]` and accessing it normally.

Comment: @lapita please elaborate your question. What do you want to achieve exactly. Your question is likely to be closed soon because "It's unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Yes, but I'm asking is there any other way for allocation other than just statically defining an array ?

Comment: @lapita: yes of cours. It's called "dynamic allocation". Use the `malloc` function. It's very basic C knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
unsigned char (*ptrtomem)[8];
unsigned char (*ptr)[8];
/* ... */
    ptrtomem = malloc(20000*8);
    ptr = ptrtomem-2500;
/* use ptr[2500][] to ptr[24999][] */
/* when done */
    free(ptrtomem);
```

or use _alloca() (or alloca() depending on compiler) if you want to allocate off the stack.